# Software Test Automation Framework (STAF) or Jenkins

Tags: testing, jenkins, build, integration, continuous

How is STAF better than compared to Jenkins + plugins in CI, testing and deployment?
Jenkins is able to achieve automated testing and deployment using plugins, then in what situations should one use a framework like STAF?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm wrong, but these two are just two different things. While STAF is

> multi-platform, multi-language framework designed around
>   the idea of reusable components, called services

the Jenkins is

> extendable continuous integration server

I assume that you accept their concept to be leveraged to help solve common development problems, such as more frequent product cycles, less preparation time, reduced testing time, more platform choices, more programming language choices, and increased Language requirements.

I think that both can help in these areas since they are a proven and mature technologies, which promote automation and reuse. Also have broad platform and language support, and provides a common infrastructure across teams.

How you'll use them in order to achieve these goals - it's up to you. And why not combine them - [JENKINS STAF+STAX Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/STAF+-+STAX+Plugin)